# Smoothness criterion using completion.

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $A\to B$ be a ring map of Noetherian commutative unital rings. Let $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq A$ and $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq B$ be primes such that $\mathfrak{q}\cap A=\mathfrak{p}$. I wonder whether the following criterion for smoothness at $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq B$ is valid

> If $\hat{A_{\mathfrak{p}}}\to \hat{B_{\mathfrak{q}}}$ is a formal power series, i.e. $\hat{B_{\mathfrak{q}}}\cong \hat{A_{\mathfrak{p}}}[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$ for some $n\geq0$, then $A\to B$ is smooth at $\mathfrak{q}$.

If it is correct, can you provide any references?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there's a finiteness issue - the map $k\to k[[x]]$ fulfills your conditions but isn't smooth because it's not of finite presentation.

Comment: @KReiser Dear KReiser, my main question is "for a morphism of schemes, when the natural transformation between local deformation functors is smooth what kind of smoothness can we have about the morphism at this point?". It turns out that smoothness between deformation functors gives the power-series condition, and then I ask to what extend the power-series condition recovers smoothness. Thanks!

Comment: You should definitely put that motivation in your question with an [edit]! You may also find it helpful to look at *formal smoothness* - this is something like smooth without the finiteness conditions.